# Convert JSON into Objects in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a json response which is fetched from server and it should be parsed as dictionary and convert it to NSObjects in Swift. How can i do this.

```
func convertJSONToObjects(object:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?) -> CommonResponse{
        var response:CommonResponse;
        if(object != nil){
            response = CommonResponse()
            var responseObject = object //It is dictionary

            var responseHeader = object["responseHeader"] //error

           response.status = responseHeader["status"] as Int //error
           //response.status is Int
        }
        return response
    }


var parsedJson  = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(object as NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &parseError) as NSDictionary
```

calling function

```
convertJSONToObjects(parsedJson)
```

Comment: I can recommend https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object` is optional. You need some kind of unwrapping optional chaining, or optional bidding.

```
if let object = object {
    var responseHeader = object["responseHeader"]
}
```

or

```
var responseHeader = object!["responseHeader"]
```

or

```
if let responseHeader = object?["responseHeader"] {
    // ...
}
```

and so on.

Comment: yes. i forget it. Thanks. i tried the next code. response.status = responseHeader["status"] as Int. It also throws an error. response.status is Int type.

Comment: `responseHeader` is `AnyObject`. It needs to be casted to `NSDictionary` or `[String:AnyObject]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a break point before:

var responseHeader = object["responseHeader"] //error

to make sure that object does contains a key named "responseHeader".

Otherwise you should let variable responseHeader to be an Optional value.

Comment: i can't run. it shows an error as "Dictionary<String,AnyObject> does not have a member named subscript" on the particular line

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class that parses JSON text and maps it to Swift structs/classes.

```
let p = CutePossumParser(json: json)

let model = Possum(
  name: p.parse("name", miss: ""),
  home: Address(
    planet: p["home"].parse("planet", miss: "")
  )
)

if !p.success { /* mapping failed */ }
```

https://github.com/exchangegroup/cute-possum-parser